# Increasing quintic polynomial

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> If
> $$
> f(x) = \frac{x^5}{5} + \frac{x^4}{4} + x^3 + \frac{kx^2}{2} + x
> $$
> is a real valued function, then find the interval for $k$ such that $f(x)$ is increasing for all $x$.

**My attempt:**
For $f'(x) \geq 0$, I have been able to ascertain that $y=-kx$ needs to be tangent to the curve
$$
x^4 + x^3 + 3x^2 + 1.
$$
But then I get a very complicated set of equations, which seem difficult to solve without the help of a computer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).